# How do I access the UserForms collection for a separate Excel instance?

Tags: vba, excel

Is there any way to get at the UserForms collection (Object Browser indicates it is a member of VBA.Global) for a separate instance of Excel? I need to check whether a form is loaded and quit the remote application appropriately if not so as not to leave any ghost processes - but I can't work out a way to detect this simply.

I could probably use a convoluted series of API calls to identify all UserForm windows ("ThunderDFrames"), then identify their parent process, then identify their parent process's hWnd, and then detect whether that matches the hWnd of the Application object it's known to be hosted by, but it would feel a lot more elegant to simply get at UserForms colelction for the application to test.

Comment: You can use the UserForms collection to iterate through all loaded user forms in an application.

Comment: I know - that's what I'm trying to do! However, the UserForms collection (unsurprisingly) does not provide information about out-of-process Userforms (i.e. those running on an Excel.Application object that isn't the one executing the code). What I'm after is the UserForms collection for xlNew in the following: `Dim xlNew as New Excel.Application`

Comment: Aha i see now. VBA.UserForms colection is obviously bound to particular process. So if u have new Excel.Application created, then the current VBA.UserForms collection does not contain the UserForms of this new process. U would need something like a super global VBA.UserForms for all running Excel instances. So i do not know how to solve this problem with VBA :-(. Of course with Win API u can find all UserForms for all Excel instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for a simpler answer - nope. [Why?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/exceldna/3ikM3M68IMQ/Zs0Sj60zpnoJ).

Becaues as @Daniel pointed out, the each memoery in different process is isolated and indpendent of each other. Hence unable to read the memeory in another process without a bit of heavy design.

The workaround would be to save UserForm's data `collection` to a workbook and read from there. Like writing into and reading from a closed workbook. That will sort of act as a memory location for you. Not efficient but do-able :) without much sweat.